# How can I unpack an arbitrary length list of IO Bool

Tags: haskell, io

I'm writing a program that should be able to simulate many instances of trying the martingale betting system with roulette. I would like `main` to take an argument giving the number of tests to perform, perform the test that many times, and then print the number of wins divided by the total number of tests. My problem is that instead of ending up with a list of `Bool` that I could filter over to count successes, I have a list of `IO Bool` and I don't understand how I can filter over that.

Here's the source code:

```
-- file: Martingale.hs
-- a program to simulate the martingale doubling system

import System.Random (randomR, newStdGen, StdGen)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

red = [1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36]

martingale :: IO StdGen -> IO Bool
martingale ioGen = do
  gen <- ioGen
  return $ martingale' 1 0 gen

martingale' :: Real a => a -> a -> StdGen -> Bool
martingale' bet acc gen
  | acc >= 5     = True
  | acc <= -100  = False
  | otherwise    = do
    let (randNumber, newGen) = randomR (0,37) gen :: (Int, StdGen)
    if randNumber `elem` red
      then martingale' 1 (acc + bet) newGen
      else martingale' (bet * 2) (acc - bet) newGen

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let iters = read $ head args
      gens = replicate iters newStdGen
      results = map martingale gens
      --results = map (<-) results
  print "THIS IS A STUB"
```

Like I have in my comments, I basically want to map `(<-)` over my list of `IO Bool`, but as I understand it, `(<-)` isn't actually a function but a keyword. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence) `:: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map martingale gens` will give you something of type `[IO Bool]`. You can then use [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) to unpack it:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

A more natural alternative is to use [`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) directly:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

i.e. you can write

```
results <- mapM martingale gens
```

Note - even after doing it this way, your code feels a bit unnatural. I can see some advantages to the structure, in particular because `martingale'` is a pure function. However having something of type `IO StdGen -> IO Bool` seems a bit odd.

I can see a couple of ways to improve it:

- make `martingale'` return an `IO` type itself and push the `newStdGen` call all the way down into it
- make `gens` use [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) rather than `replicate`

You may want to head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com for more comprehensive feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about that function and I didn't know codereview existed either.

Comment: You should look around the functions in Control.Monad to get an idea of what generic operations are available on monadic types like `IO`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html